# Android TV, не работает Фокус в Webview на IFRAME

Tags: javascript, java, android

Пишу приложение на андроид ТВ и не работает Фокус в Webview на IFRAME. Помогите. Дело в том что это не тач устройство и без мышки управление осуществляется с пульта кейкодами  37 38 39 40 то есть мышка исключена он выбирает только родные элементы на странице

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function setFocusThickboxIframe() {
    var iframe = $("#TB_iframeContent")[0];
    iframe.contentWindow.focus();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#id_cmd_open").click(function(){
      /*
         run thickbox code here to open lightbox,
         like tb_show("google this!", "http://www.google.com");
       */
      setTimeout(setFocusThickboxIframe, 100);
      return false;
   });
});
```

Сам нашел ответ